# A TFS 2010 Gated Check-in Build leaves me with a .vspscc file with pending changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, checkin

I have a branch in TFS 2010 that has a Gates Check-in build associated.
If I add a file to my project and do a "Check in", the gated check-in build kicks in before my changes are checked in... Which is all good!

After the build completes (sucessfully), Visual Studio askes me to "Reconsile" my Pending Changes. In this case my Pending Changes windows shows two changed files **before** I press the Reconsile button:

- MyProject.csproj (this project that has the new file added)
- MyNewFile.cs (the new file added)

But after the reconsile operation I'm left with a new file in the Pending Changes window:

- MyProject.csproj.vspscc

If I right click this file and select "Compare" -> "With Latest Version..." I'm told the files are identical, so basically I can just ignore the file or undo it...

But it's there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the power tool command TFPT UU to fix this.

Comment: Good workaround! But it sure would be nice, if TFS simply knew not mark the .vspscc files as being changed. Oh well... :)

Comment: I have given the product team of Team Build this feedback already. I am sure in VS vNext the experience will be better. For now it is due to technical issues that it works like this. Because only modified files are included in a changeset, it can only undo and get the files in the changeset. That is why the other files will stay checked out.

Comment: For those looking for the link to the power toys: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f